# How do you change the visibility of widgets inside individual listview rows from onlistitemclick in Android?

Tags: android, listview, visibility

My ultimate goal is to change the source of the information in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List6.html) from an array to a cursor.  Here is a link to the [full code](http://pastebin.com/VYhwrnj2).  The gist of it is that you click a row in the list, and the body pops open below the listed title, and you tap it again and the body is gone.  I am not looking to remember if the note is open, nor am I looking to keep it open through view recycling, nor close all others when you open one or any other fancy permutation I can think of off the top of my head.

Everything mostly works, but when the onListItemClick event handler fires, changes the visibility, and `notifyDataSetChanged()`s, the list does strange things, including taking two clicks to change the visibility, and not remeasuring itself, leading to the list row only making room for itself every third click or so.

A previous attempt lead to a perfectly working list, excepting that on click, the chunk in every row that I wanted to hide and show would hide and show, and the list in the tutorial works perfectly, but of course uses static sizes in everything, so is little more than a template.

I am convinced that the problem is either getting the visibility information attached to the list row or changing it once it has been set.

Here is the `onListItemClick`:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ((NotesCursorAdapter) getListAdapter()).toggle(position, v);
}
```

with the toggle method inside the `NotesCursorAdapter`:

```
    public void toggle(int position, View view) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.mExpanded[position] = !holder.mExpanded[position];
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

the `ViewHolder` outside of the `NotesCursorAdapter`:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView body;
    public boolean mExpanded[];
}
```

and the `NotesCursorAdapter` itself:

```
class NotesCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private static final int VISIBLE = 0;
    private static final int GONE = 8;

    public NotesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.body = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.body);
        holder.mExpanded = new boolean[cursor.getCount()];
        rowView.setTag(holder);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_TITLE))
                + holder.mExpanded[cursor.getPosition()]);
        holder.body.setText(cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        holder.body
                .setVisibility(holder.mExpanded[cursor.getPosition()] ? VISIBLE : GONE);

    }

    public void toggle(int position, View view) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.mExpanded[position] = !holder.mExpanded[position];
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I am at a loss on where to look next.  Do I need to make my own `getView()` method?  Would I get anything useful out of `getItem()`?  Am I totally crazy for trying to use a `listview` like this?

I have done more investigating, and the code is working, but the on click events seem to be effecting the opposite views.  What I mean by that, is that when you click the top list item, it effects the bottom list item.  When you click the second from the top, it effects the second from the bottom.  If there is an odd number of list items, the middle list item works perfectly.  In some way, whatever way I am using to determine the id of the view that I am effecting is flipped.  Does the listview number things from the bottom up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K, I got it figured out.  The settings were not displaying right because a ListView has two layers:  the View layer and the data layer.  The way that android recycles Views in a ListView means that which View is being used to display the data does not matter.  So to use a CursorAdapter, the View information goes in the newView() method, and the data information from the Cursor goes in the bindView() method.  Here is the fixed stuff:

Not much changed here, only passing what is needed:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ((NotesCursorAdapter) l.getAdapter()).toggle(position);
}
```

The view holder only gets information needed to construct the view, not any information in the view, including the visible state:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView body;
    public Button button;
}
```

The visible state is tracked in an array as a property of the adapter.  The view information is in the newView() method and the data information is in the bindView() method.  When the notifyDataSetChanged() fires, the views are all recycled, and the data is re-layered on.  Because the view info and the data info are separate, it does not matter which view gets matched up with which data.

```
    class NotesCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private boolean[] expandedArray;

    public NotesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        expandedArray = new boolean[c.getCount()];
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title= (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.body= (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.body);
        holder.button= (Button) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.button);

        rowView.setTag(holder);
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        holder.body.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        holder.body
                .setVisibility(expandedArray[cursor.getPosition()] ? View.VISIBLE
                        : View.GONE);
        holder.button
                .setVisibility(expandedArray[cursor.getPosition()] ? View.VISIBLE
                        : View.GONE);
        holder.button.setTag(cursor.getPosition());

    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        expandedArray[position] = !expandedArray[position];
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And for completeness, here is the mapping from the ListAdapter mapping to be called in onCreate(), onActivityResult(), or whenever the list needs reloaded:

```
private void fillData() {
    notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);
    NotesCursorAdapter notes = new NotesCursorAdapter(this, notesCursor);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented something similar to this from List6 of API Demos as well. Mine is working perfectly (all be it I had trouble with having focus from an ImageButton). I used a SimpleCursorAdapter however I suppose you could use a CursorAdapter. I modified your code quite a bit.

Not sure why you also added the View parameter so I took that out.

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> mExpanded;

@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ((NotesCursorAdapter) getListAdapter()).toggle(position);
    }
```

Your ViewHolder. Pretty simple, just that the constructor receives parameters from your getView.

```
private class ViewHolder {
private TextView title;
private TextView body;

public ViewHolder(View convertView, boolean expanded) {

title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.body);

//not sure if you need this...
//body.setVisibility(expanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}

public void setTitle(int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(PowersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
}

public void setBody(int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    body.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(PowersDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    body.setVisibility(expanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }       
}
```

Here is your custom ListAdapter. I am not sure why you wanted to use bindView and newView with a ViewHolder, Android takes care of that with bindView and newViews. But you need to use a ViewHolder in this case so getView is necessary.

```
private class NotesCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Cursor cursor;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public NotesCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
    this.cursor = cursor;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mExpanded = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;          
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        populateExpanded();

        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView, mExpanded.get(position));

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        holder.setTitle(position);
        holder.setBody(position);
        holder.setExpanded(mExpanded.get(position));

        return rowView;
}

private void populateExpanded() {
    // We want our hidden TextView to not be expanded initially
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        mExpanded.add(false);
    }
}

public void toggle(int position) {
if (mExpanded.get(position) == false) {
    mExpanded.set(position, true);
}
else {
    mExpanded.set(position, false);
}
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here is how you can map it with a SimpleCursorAdapter

```
setListAdapter(new NotesCursorAdapter(MyClass.this, R.layout.row, cursor,
            new String[] { "my_title", "my_body" }, new int[] { R.id.MyTitleTextView, R.id.MyBodyTextView }));
```

Comment: I am trying to get your code to work.  Where is setExpanded() called and how can I set the size of the array on the holder when the holder is null?  I had the view as a parameter because I was trying different things, and so I made the constructor to accept whatever I could get.  I am using  CursorAdapter instead of a SimpleCursorAdaptor because I am eventually going to be doing non-simple things, and I don't think that SimpleCursorAdapter is meant to do much more than map strings to TextViews and ImageViews.  CursorAdapter requires code for the newView() and bindView() methods.

Comment: Ok I fixed some errors. I created a method to set initial values to the boolean array. Just like they predefined it in List6 (but that was a static cheap way and not dynamic). SimpleCursorAdapter can do everything you wanted. In my app, I have a textview (like your title) and a linear layout under it that is has its visibility as GONE. It contains two imagebuttons (with onclicklisteners) and a textview (displays a number). It is very non simple. Exactly what do you have in mind you are going to do later on?

Comment: I got it figured out. The problem was that I was tracking the status of the expanded view in both the adapter and the view holder.  Once I added a boolean array into the adapter class and then used that to determine the state of the views, the app started doing stranger stuff, and when I removed the visibility boolean from the view holder, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.  Making me try a simple cursor adapter led me to really look at how the getView()/newView()/bindView() system works, and made me really take a hard look at where the objects were coming from.

Comment: Excellent! Not a problem! It is really a conscience that I came across this question because I was working on basically the same thing at the same time. But I changed the code once more because I had problems with ArrayIndexOutofBounds with just Arrays so I switched to ArrayLists.